# Minimum amount of edges that needs to be traversed to visit all vertices... or something like that

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, graph, pathfinding

So I have this problem, where I'm given `m` connections over `n` vertices. The vertices are labeled `1...n`.

Example input:

```
4 5
1 2
2 3
2 4
3 1
3 4
```

The first row contains the numbers `n` and `m`. The following `m` rows tells me what connections exist. It's safe to assume the connections contain every number `1...n` at least once.

The above input would represent a graph like below:

[image]

## Problem Description

> The actual problem states, that there are `m` translations that need
>   to be done. What is the minimum amount of translators that have to be
>   hired, so that all the translations can be done? The translators can
>   work together, for example, if translator `A` can translate from
>   language `1` to language `2`, and translator `B` can translate from
>   language `3` to language `1`, then a translation `3->2` can be done
>   with those two translators working together (`3->1->2`).

Here is my working code:

```
import java.util.*;    

public class Translators {

    public static int n;
    public static ArrayList<Edge>[] connsFrom;
    public static ArrayList<Edge>[] connsTo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // an external class working like Scanner, but faster
        IO io = new IO();

        n = io.nextInt();     // number of languages
        int m = io.nextInt(); // number of translations

        // number of translations that need be done to language i
        int[] to = new int[n+1];

        // number of translations that need be done from language i
        int[] from = new int[n+1];

        // translations that need be done from language i
        connsFrom = new ArrayList[n+1];

        // translations that need be done to language i
        connsTo = new ArrayList[n+1];

        // init
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            connsFrom[i] = new ArrayList<>();
            connsTo[i] = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            int a = io.nextInt();    // translation from
            int b = io.nextInt();    // translation to
            Edge e = new Edge(b, 0);
            connsFrom[a].add(e);
            connsTo[b].add(e);
        }

        // init an edge's weight to 1 when it's the only edge from a vertex,
        // or only edge to a vertex.
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (connsFrom[i].size() == 1) connsFrom[i].get(0).weight = 1;
            if (connsTo[i].size() == 1) connsTo[i].get(0).weight = 1;
        }        

        // hired translators
        HashSet<Integer> translators = new HashSet<>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (Edge e : connsFrom[i]) {

                // find the path that has the biggest cost
                ArrayList<Edge> path = findPath(i, e.to);

                // hire all translators on the path, and change the
                // weight of all used edges to 1.
                for (Edge e2 : path) {
                    translators.add(e2.to);
                    e2.weight = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(translators.size());

    }

    /**
     * Dijkstra, returning the path with maximal cost.
     */
    public static ArrayList<Edge> findPath(int source, int goal) {
        int[] approx = new int[n+1];        
        boolean[] fin = new boolean[n+1];

        PriorityQueue<Edge> q = new PriorityQueue<>();
        q.add(new Edge(source, 0));

        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            Edge e = q.poll();

            if (fin[e.to]) continue; // already visited            
            fin[e.to] = true;

            if (e.to == goal) return e.path;

            for (Edge e2 : connsFrom[e.to]) {
                if (e.weight + e2.weight > approx[e2.to]) {
                    approx[e2.to] = e.weight + e2.weight;

                    Edge ne = new Edge(e2.to, e.weight + e2.weight);
                    ne.path = new ArrayList<>(e.path);
                    ne.path.add(e2);
                    q.add(ne);
                }                
            }

        }

        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

}

class Pair {
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public Pair(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Pair p = (Pair) o;
        return a == p.a && b == p.b;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 61 * hash + this.a;
        hash = 61 * hash + this.b;
        return hash;
    }
}

class Edge implements Comparable<Edge> {
    public int to;
    public int weight;
    public ArrayList<Edge> path = new ArrayList<>();
    public Edge(int to, int weight) {
        this.to = to;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Edge o) {
        return Long.compare(o.weight, weight); // bigger first
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "-" + weight + "-> " + to;
    }
}
```

My idea was to init the weight of all the edges to 0 at first, but if an edge is the only edge going to or coming from a vertex, change its weight to 1. Also, when we find a path from a to b, we change the weight of all the edges on that path to 1. This way the searching algorithm always finds a path that has the most vertices that have been used before.

This code gives me the correct answer, however, `n` can be as big as `5 * 10^4`, and `m` can be as big as `10^5`, for which the code runs too slow.

My question: is there a way of optimizing this? Do I need a different approach altogether, or can my code be tweaked?

Comment: Is it your intention that in the example you cannot translate from language 4 to any other language? Does that matter? It's a bit strange that in this particular scenario a translator can only translate one way.

Comment: @DevonParsons If there is an edge from vertex `v` to `u`, it simply means that a translation from `v` to `u` must be done. Language 4 doesn't have edges to other languages because there mustn't be a translation from language 4 to any other language.

Comment: Ah, I understand, I thought you were displaying the available translators, but you are displaying the translations required